# Reviewing deleted posts (10K users)

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions, 10k

I've been hitting Data Explorer pretty hard lately attempting to purge not-an-answer answers from questions. You all have seen the type.

> I'm having the exact same problem. Has anyone fixed this?

There are a lot of types out there. Anyway, 10K users at least can at least see what I'm deleting. Over in the 10K tools, there is a link on the Links tab.

[image: Deleted Posts link]

After you click on that link, you will get a list of all posts that have been deleted. Right this moment, I kind of monopolize that list, but self-deletes show up in here as well as mod-deletes. It's all there. Since you're a 10K+ user, clicking on any of those links will bring you to the deleted item. If you don't think it should be deleted, vote to undelete it.

[image: Undelete button]

Perhaps not that one, but maybe one of the ones I nuked doesn't deserve it. If so, click that big red (or dark gray if your eyes work like that) link. It'll show up on another 10K tool, on the Delete tab.

[image: Delete Page]

(as a side note, 10K users can vote-to-delete any already closed questions. The above screencap shows one that has a vote already.)

I think I've seen something in the undelete-votes list exactly once, so it's a rare thing. If I see one of my deletes in there? I'll undelete it. No worries.

So, if you're a 10K, please cross-check me.

Comment: In regard to deleting closed questions, there appears to be some sort of relationship between previously cast votes for (or against) the question and the number required to delete it. Some require only a few delete votes, whereas others require an unobtainable number. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Yes, there is. Unfortunately, I'd have to delve into MSO-search to dig that out since I don't know what it is. The 'favorite server names' question required something like 317 votes to delete back when we tried. Normal questions are closer to 3.